# How can add "templates " and "statics" folder in Django 3.1

Tags: django-2.0, django-3.1

> setting.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

#TEMPLATES_DIR = path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')    #it dosen't work
#STATICS_DIR = path.join(BASE_DIR, 'statics')             #it also dosen't work

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '0#nf@$8nm5jb0)meuq&j6kztt534@nhk)k&$zh=#emcxi7_7fo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'musicianapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'musicianList.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'musicianList.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATICS_DIR,
]
```

Please consern on the **top** and **3rd top** line where  is the main difference from **Djago2.7 version**

> In Djnago2.7 where imported os as below,

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

> and I used the below code for connecting templates and statics forlder

```
TEMPLATES_DIR =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATICS_DIR =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"statics")
```

> But there is differece in form **Djnago 3.1**  `from pathlib imported Path`  given below,

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

> and the os techinques dosen't works as below

```
TEMPLATES_DIR =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATICS_DIR =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"statics")
```

*How can I make connection with templates and statics folder, need help.*

**Note:** I create templates and statics folders in main projects where already presented **manage.py** and **db.sqlite3** file. below the screenshot of my projects direction,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the top of the `settings.py` file, you'll see `BASE_DIR` is using `pathlib`:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

Because of this, you no longer need `os` to join the paths, you can simply do:

```
STATICS_DIR = BASE_DIR / "statics"
```

This is new in 3.1 - you can read about it in the release notes here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/overriding-templates/, but if nothing happens then it should be the Refactoring problem especially when using PyCharm. So, you need to revert your changes. It worked for me.